# How to find the version of mozilla in add-on script in add-on sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to determine the version of firefox on which my add-on will run. I know we can do that using jquery in content-script(page-mod) . But i want to know it before any content-script is attached to any page.

To clarify further...
In my add-on script (main.js), I am making a request to my server,as a part of which i need to send the browser version and browser name ,to recieve some browser-version specific settings.

I can determine this using `jQuery.browser.version` in content-script after the very first page is loaded after installation of the add-on and communicate it to the add-on script using `self.emit('event-name',payload)` and store it using simple-storage. On subsequent requests i will have to check whether browser version has been updated.

What i wanted was a more direct way of doing it. I thought may be add-on sdk already provides it somewhere.

Comment: In Stack Overflow, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Comment: @Sid : I posted this assuming that no one is not going to waste time searching/researching/coding for me but if any one has already done this , he/she might help me do it faster. Also firefox addon-sdk being quite new, there are very few posts on stack overflow .Also google always leads to the sdk's documentation, in which i had found no luck earlier. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer using add-on-sdk's low-level api xul-app:

```
    var xul_app=require('xul-app');
    console.log(xul_app.version);
    console.log(xul_app.name);
```